# Spring Cloud Gateway and CORS header

Tags: java, cors, spring-cloud-gateway

I am trying to proxy-forward a request using [`org.springframework.cloud.gateway.mvc.ProxyExchange`](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/blob/master/spring-cloud-gateway-mvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/gateway/mvc/ProxyExchange.java).
The call is working fine.

In my scenario I like to integrate it with the browser calls, but
get a CORS-header issue there.

(1) Source in the controller:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/public**", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> forwardHttpRequestForGet(
    HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
    @RequestParam MultiValueMap<String, String> requestParams,
  @RequestHeader HttpHeaders requestHeaders,
  ProxyExchange<byte[]> proxy) throws Exception {
  
  ResponseEntity<byte[]> responseEntity = cloudGatewayService.proxyForwardToApplication(httpServletRequest, requestParams,requestHeaders, proxy);
  return responseEntity;
}
```

(2) Source of used `CloudGatewayService`:

```java
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> proxyForwardToApplication(
    HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
    MultiValueMap<String, String> requestParams,
    HttpHeaders requestHeaders, ProxyExchange<byte[]> proxy) throws Exception {
  
  String authorizationHeader = httpServletRequest.getHeader(AUTHORIZATION_HEADER);
  String forwardUrl = "newUrl"
  
  return proxy.sensitive("cookie")
    .headers(requestHeaders)
    .uri(forwardUrl).get();
}
```

How can I add CORS support for *Spring Cloud Gateway* ?

Comment: Have you tried adding configuration in application.yml as per documentation? https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/reference/html/#cors-configuration

Comment: @mehowthe I have gone through the document. Will try this

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is nothing specific to cloud MVC. Even if it is a proxy, we have to add CORS support to the web application.

As it is a spring boot project, I have added spring security as well here. Added a filter which can populate the headers did the job.

Note : add whatever required headers for your OPTION call (preflight),
Also support GET,POST, DELETE, etc calls accordingly.

The response headers can be added to the http response

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).